# Pixel-art sprite distortion with 1:1 pixel ratio

Tags: unity, pixel, pixel-art

So I've been studying the Unity's PPU, pixel density, camera settings topic to make my game pixel-perfect. I've set everything in a way that my screen pixel to sprite texel ratio equals 1.

The art looks very good and crisp overall on the game view...

But!

There are still some minor distortions and I don't know where it comes from.

Take a look at this example:

[image]

In this example my settings are:

- **Screen**: 870x510
- **PPU**: 100
- **Camera size**: 2.55
- **Pixel snap** on Sprite material: on

The issue happens when I move the sprite manually by ~0.001 values on the Y axis. Same happens on the X axis.

Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: 2.55 and 100 aren't powers of 2, so it's possible you're experiencing some rounding in the math when performed in binary. What happens if you make your PPU 128, for example? (Adjusting your positions & camera accordingly)

Comment: In fact, why 0.001 values? This would be correct behavior if your grid were along pixel boundaries or straddling the midpoints between pixels, depending on your sampling algorithm (it appears to be 'nearest'.) I would try to consider what your screen would be doing with a 2x2 resolution to rule out initial alignment. I have no experience with Unity, so I apologize if I have a poor grasp of the problem (but it sounds like one I've had in rendering, image editing, etc.)

Comment: @DMGregory Well, the problem did disappear. What's interesting is that when I used something like a 1675/946 res with 118 PPU and 4.008474 orto (I'm messing around in Free Aspect mode) the problem also doesn't exist, so is it really a problem of numbers not being powers of 2?

Comment: I wouldn't be satisfied with that... if it was due to a change in rounding, it would probably still exist until you determined and fixed the original cause. Check this guide for comments on these settings: https://twitter.com/davitsu/status/956499799133573120 -> filtering off, ortho size coupled with PPU, and what I suspect to be an issue, 'snap to grid' should be on for sprites of this size. Powers of two should not be a problem; 2.55 actually makes sense to me - (2^8-1)/100 - although I would be curious to see what 2.56 did. Your ortho didn't make sense to me, sorry, was it arbitrary?

Comment: @JohnP Camera Ortho Size (2.55) = Screen Height (510) divided by PPU (100) divided by 2 (since it's a half-extent)

Comment: @DMGregory No, I meant 4.008474. Anyway, my earlier comment about aligned grids was getting at the possibility that the coordinate (0,0) might be the lower left corner of the 0th pixel, as opposed to the center, where it should read the same sample value before and after your micro-adjustments. Instead, have you tried aligning the texture one half pixel over, so the 0th pixel spans (-0.5,-0.5) to (0.5,0.5) in pixel space? Snap to grid might take care of this decision for you, I'm not sure.

Comment: @JohnP Pixel snapping unfortunately does not fix the issue. Additionaly I have all the settings set for pixel-perfect of course (the ones you've mentioned eariler). Actually, after messing around with the settings I can reproduce this issue in a position difference of 0.00000001 (even on PPU = 128), but I guess trying to solve this kind of a problem has already its name. It's called "overengineering" :)

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure about that - there appear to be several decent tools tackling these problems. And is it really overengineering if the SNES got it right? -- As an afterthought, any chance small motions like this can be made in texture space more precisely than view/projection space?

Comment: IMO depends on what you want to achieve. In Unity I will probably never move my character by 0.00000001 values, so the problem might just not exist in a real-world usage (in this particular case I'm moving it manually on the scene). So it appears to be a little bit waste of time. Of course, I'd love to know the solution, but I'd rather have a working gameplay than to know the solution for this edge-case problem (as these kind of mysterious issues might totally take a bunch of hours to actually solve it).

Comment: @JohnP What do you mean by "texture space"?

Comment: @JohnP Pardon! I've just noticed that you had something else in mind by saying "pixel snapping". I was just using the Unity built in Sprite material with "Pixel snap" option. Not sure if it does the thing you thought of.

Comment: @sarneeh As far as I understand, you're moving the sprite around, and both its texture and the way the texture is mapped to its surface are completely independent from the sprite's motion, right? One way or another you're getting aliasing only when you move the sprite. Your pixel art is discrete, gets mapped to "UV space" (as in the continuous `(u,v)` parameters on its new surface) and back through your ortho to project into discrete screen space. If it's wrinkling/aliasing, can the texture move instead?

Comment: @sarneeh "I will probably never move my character by 0.00000001 values" -- are you positive this only happens *below* reasonable thresholds? I would have dropped it if I thought the small scale was to blame. Instead I assumed you were pushing it to its logical limit (if even miniscule motions cause tearing, it must be unstable, or inaccurate in general, etc.) Rounding errors in your scale would mean you could be seeing z-fighting, misaligned geometry, etc. so I would assume the 0.00000001 isn't special because it's small, but that it's significant because it doesn't need to be any bigger.

Comment: @JohnP I guess this is possible in the engine but I don't think it's something that would be recommended to do. Or maybe I just don't understand what you're saying as I'm a real beginner in the game development topic :) P.S. these kind of conversations are really hard on Stack :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77029/discussion-between-sarneeh-and-john-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that there was some kind of artifact going on caused by how the sprite meshes were constructed.

When i changed the **mesh type** of the sprite to **rect** - the problem disappeared. Here's a comparison of a sprite with mesh type **tight** (left) and **rect** (right):

[image]

Here's how the sprites were mapped to meshes in Unity:

[image]